# Changing the height is not reflecting in iphone screen

Tags: iphone, uiview

I am trying to display half of my view only in my iPhone screen.

For that i have opened my view controller xib, change the view's color to red , change the default width*height from 320*480 to 320*200, save it and build the application but simulator is showing the view in full screen mode.Not in 320 * 200 mode.What is the solution for this problem?

Also i can't able to change the x and y coordinate in my xib also. How can i able to do so?

Comment: Post how you are adding this View Controller to the currently shown View.

Comment: The view in which i am working is the main view controller xib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIViewController that is managing your view always resize its self.view so that it takes the whole screen.

(This way your view is automatically adapted according to if you have a tabbar, a navbar, if you have a call pending that makes the status bar bigger, …)

You instead need to use a subview of your view if you need to display sthg only half of the screen.

Comment: Instead of relay on these xib i willl finally choose to do this by using subview programatically.

Answer (score 0):

if we want to display view in half of your screen then take a uiview with proper size. lit will be work properly.I had also face some problem 6 months before and solved in this way